# Replace windows path with linux path using sed in a file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed, replace, path

I have one configuration file than i need change automatic with a script..

- Original path: `G:\xampp\www\myweb`
- New path: `/srv/myweb/public_html`

I try to use all options posible with

```
sed -i \"s/G:\\xampp\\www\\myweb/\/srv\/myweb\/public_html/g\" myfile.php
```

But i can not make this work, any help???

The solution must be using bash because is runing inside a huge script.. thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1):

Try to unescape the quotes surrounding the command and escape `\` like this:

```
sed -i "s/G:\\\xampp\\\www\\\myweb/\/srv\/myweb\/public_html/g" file
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
sed 's|G:\\xampp\\www\\myweb|/srv/myweb/public_html|g' -i myfile.php
```

We're using `|` as delimiter in `sed` search command (instead of the default `/`) to avoid escaping of `/`, and a single quotes around everything to avoid double escaping of `\`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'foo G:\xampp\www\myweb bar' | sed 's#G:\\xampp\\www\\myweb#/srv/myweb/public_html#g'
foo /srv/myweb/public_html bar
```

Use single quotes and use a delimiter different than `/` that doesn't appear in search/replacement terms (any character other than `\` and newline characters can be used as delimiter)

`\` is meta character, use `\\` to represent it literally